# Выбор определенных значений из строк в R

Tags: r, rstudio

Есть данные energy.

Из колонки `Condition` (где есть значения `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`) нужно выбрать только `A`, `B`, `C` и `E`.

Как это правильно сделать? Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

покажу на примере встроенного набора данных `chickwts`.

всего в наборе 71 наблюдение:

```r
nrow(chickwts)
#> [1] 71
```

значения у переменной `feed` такие:

```r
levels(chickwts$feed)
#> [1] "casein"    "horsebean" "linseed"   "meatmeal"  "soybean"   "sunflower"
```

со значением `"casein"` — 12 наблюдений:

```r
nrow(chickwts[chickwts$feed == "casein",])
#> [1] 12
```

со значением `"horsebean"` — 10:

```r
nrow(chickwts[chickwts$feed == "horsebean",])
#> [1] 10
```

соответственно, в сумме должно быть 22 наблюдения со значениями либо `"casein"`, либо `"horsebean"`.

проверяем:

```r
nrow(chickwts[chickwts$feed %in% c("casein","horsebean"),])
#> [1] 22
```

так и есть. мы только что успешно отфильтровали набор данных по условию: переменная `feed` равна либо `"casein"`, либо `"horsebean"`.

---

а можно и обратное условие использовать — например, получить наблюдения, в которых переменная `feed` **не** равна `"horsebean"` (оператор `!=`). таких будет 61 штука (71 - 10):

```r
nrow(chickwts[chickwts$feed != "horsebean",])
#> [1] 61
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>